# Is bad to use <input type="date" /> in 2021?

Tags: html, reactjs

I saw some articles that says it is not good to use , but they are outdated, some of then were write 2 / 3 years ago. So I ask if in 2021 is possible to use it without give a bad experience to the user.

Comment: We actually use a library to replace the date inputs with something more styled but we actually don't use this when someone is accessing our site using mobiles/tablets because the built-in date selector for Android and iOS are actually pretty good so there's no need to restyle them

Comment: [Each input types](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) is very useful for on-screen keyboard such as Android, IOS keyboards as @apokryfos said. It is standards not outdated. If somewhere said outdated they are already really outdated. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My application is mainly for computer users, but it can be opened by mobile too. What I'm worry about is a user open the application and the input type date don't work (for example, old web browser will show a input type text instead type date).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<input type="date">`. Almost every browser support it except `internet explorer` as you know `internet explorer` is already outdated.

> But `<input type="datetime">` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime)

Here is the code how to use:

```
<form action="https://example.com">
  <label>
    Enter your birthday:
    <input type="date" name="bday">
  </label>

  <p><button>Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

[More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)